# Vue JS console template error "tag <li> has no matching end tag."

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Here is my code snippet, I am using to change the color depending on the name of the character

It gives an error that the li tag is not properly closed, but i see the tag is closed but i find some error during conditional check

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong in the conditional check

```
<div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="part in scene">
                <div v-if:"part.character === 'MACBETH'">
                <span style="color:red">{{part.character}}</span>
                <p style="color:red">{{part.dialogue}}</p>
                </div>
                <div v-else-if:"{{part.character}} === \"LADY MACBETH\"">
                <span style="color:blue">{{part.character}}</span>
                <p style="color:blue">{{part.dialogue}}</p>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                <span>{{part.character}}</span>
                <p>{{part.dialogue}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        
        data:{
            //Scene from http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/macbeth.1.7.html
            scene:[
                {character:'MACBETH', dialogue:"Hath he ask'd for me?"},
                {character:'LADY MACBETH', dialogue:"Know you not he has?"},
                {character:'MACBETH', dialogue:"We will proceed no further in this business:\nHe hath honour'd me of late; and I have bought\nGolden opinions from all sorts of people,\nWhich would be worn now in their newest gloss,\nNot cast aside so soon."},
                {character:'LADY MACBETH', dialogue:"Was the hope drunk\nWherein you dress'd yourself? hath it slept since?\nAnd wakes it now, to look so green and pale\nAt what it did so freely? From this time\nSuch I account thy love. Art thou afeard\nTo be the same in thine own act and valour\nAs thou art in desire? Wouldst thou have that\nWhich thou esteem'st the ornament of life,\nAnd live a coward in thine own esteem,\nLetting 'I dare not' wait upon 'I would,'\nLike the poor cat i' the adage?"}   
            ]
        }
        
    });
    </script>
```

Console error

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

tag <li> has no matching end tag.

1  |  <div id="app">
2  |        <ul>
3  |            <li v-for="part in scene">
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
4  |                  <div v-if:"part.character="==" 'macbeth'="">
5  |                <span style="color:red">{{part.character}}</span>

(found in <Root>)
```

Comment: `v-if: "part.character =etc` should be `v-if="part.character = etc` should it not?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code

This should be correct:

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="part in scene">

 <!-- <div v-if:"part.character === 'MACBETH'"> -->
               ^
      <div v-if="part.character === 'MACBETH'">

        <span style="color:red">{{part.character}}</span>
        <p style="color:red">{{part.dialogue}}</p>
      </div>

 <!-- <div v-else-if:"{{part.character}} === \"LADY MACBETH\""> -->
                    ^ ^^              ^^     ^^            ^^
      <div v-else-if="part.character === 'LADY MACBETH'">

        <span style="color:blue">{{part.character}}</span>
        <p style="color:blue">{{part.dialogue}}</p>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <span>{{part.character}}</span>
        <p>{{part.dialogue}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your `v-if` statements are wrong. You're using `:` in `v-if:` when you should be using the `=` like `v-if=` and `v-else-if=`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code, maybe I'm missing something related to the implementation:

1. Use = in the v-if and v-else-if statement, you're using :, so change v-if: to v-if=, same for v-else-if
2. This line `v-if="{{part.character}} === \"LADY MACBETH\""` is weird, you should use `part.character`, so remove the curly braces `{{ }}`, and also use `'LADY MACBETH'` in order to have the comparison working

Let me know if maybe I'm missing something.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="part in scene">
                <div v-if="part.character === 'MACBETH'">
                <span style="color:red">{{part.character}}</span>
                <p style="color:red">{{part.dialogue}}</p>
                </div>
                <div v-else-if="part.character === 'LADY MACBETH'">
                <span style="color:blue">{{part.character}}</span>
                <p style="color:blue">{{part.dialogue}}</p>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                <span>{{part.character}}</span>
                <p>{{part.dialogue}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        
        data:{
            //Scene from http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/macbeth.1.7.html
            scene:[
                {character:'MACBETH', dialogue:"Hath he ask'd for me?"},
                {character:'LADY MACBETH', dialogue:"Know you not he has?"},
                {character:'MACBETH', dialogue:"We will proceed no further in this business:\nHe hath honour'd me of late; and I have bought\nGolden opinions from all sorts of people,\nWhich would be worn now in their newest gloss,\nNot cast aside so soon."},
                {character:'LADY MACBETH', dialogue:"Was the hope drunk\nWherein you dress'd yourself? hath it slept since?\nAnd wakes it now, to look so green and pale\nAt what it did so freely? From this time\nSuch I account thy love. Art thou afeard\nTo be the same in thine own act and valour\nAs thou art in desire? Wouldst thou have that\nWhich thou esteem'st the ornament of life,\nAnd live a coward in thine own esteem,\nLetting 'I dare not' wait upon 'I would,'\nLike the poor cat i' the adage?"}   
            ]
        }
        
    });
    </script>
```